# Algorithm for tagging list of substrings from a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, optimization, substring

I have a list of utterances(strings)/corpus as the follows,

```
List<string> allUtterances = new List<string>
    {
    "c2's are above the hierarchy than c1's",
    "c2's are better than c1's",
    "get me a group of 10 c1's",
    "he is a c2",
    "he was a c two",
    "hey i am a c1",
    "jdsaxkjhasx",
    "khndsmcsdfcs",
    "my competency is c2",
    "none intent",
    "she is still a c 1",
    "this is a none intent, please ignore",
    "we are hiring fresh c1's"
};
```

---

This is the class schema:

```
public class ListEntity
{
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Sublist> subLists { get; set; }
}

public class Sublist
{
    public string canonicalForm { get; set; }
    public List<string> list { get; set; }
}
```

---

And this is a sample POCO:

```
    List<ListEntity> listEntities = new List<ListEntity>
    {
        new ListEntity
        {
            name = "Competency",
            subLists = new List<Sublist>
            {
                new Sublist
                {
                    canonicalForm = "C1",
                    list = new List<string>
                    {
                        "c1",
                        "c one",
                        "c 1",
                        "C 1",
                        "C1",
                        "C one",
                        "C ONE"
                    }
                },
                new Sublist
                {
                    canonicalForm = "C2",
                    list = new List<string>
                    {
                        "c2",
                        "c two",
                        "c 2",
                        "C 2",
                        "C2",
                        "C two",
                        "C TWO"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var canonicalForms = listEntities.Select(x => x.subLists.Select(y => y.list).ToList()).ToList();
```

---

Suppose if I have an utterance of the following from the above mentioned list allUtterances:

```
 "query": "C2's are better than C1's"
```

I want to get the following output for the above utterance:

```
{
      "entity": "c2",
      "type": "Competency",
      "startIndex": 0,
      "endIndex": 1,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "C2"
        ]
      }
},
{
      "entity": "c1",
      "type": "Competency",
      "startIndex": 21,
      "endIndex": 22,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "C1"
        ]
      }
}
```

The rules with which I want to match is as follows:

For every utterance in the `allUtterances list`, If the utterance text contains a value from the property `list` of the class sublist I want to extract the **start** and **end** positions and mark them with the appropriate key which is the `canonicalForm` in this case update the type key in my JSON payload with the  `name` property in the ListEntityClass.

---

I have tried the following approach:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListEntityProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> allUtterances = new List<string>
            {
                "c2's are above the hierarchy than c1's",
                "c2's are better than c1's",
                "get me a group of 10 c1's",
                "he is a c2",
                "he was a c two",
                "hey i am a c1",
                "jdsaxkjhasx",
                "khndsmcsdfcs",
                "my competency is c2",
                "none intent",
                "she is still a c 1",
                "this is a none intent, please ignore",
                "we are hiring fresh c1's"
            };

            List<ListEntity> listEntities = new List<ListEntity>
            {
                new ListEntity
                {
                    name = "Competency",
                    subLists = new List<Sublist>
                    {
                        new Sublist
                        {
                            canonicalForm = "C1",
                            list = new List<string>
                            {
                                "c1",
                                "c one",
                                "c 1",
                                "C 1",
                                "C1",
                                "C one",
                                "C ONE"
                            }
                        },
                        new Sublist
                        {
                            canonicalForm = "C2",
                            list = new List<string>
                            {
                                "c2",
                                "c two",
                                "c 2",
                                "C 2",
                                "C2",
                                "C two",
                                "C TWO"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


            List<Tuple<string, string, List<string>>> ListEntityLookup = new List<Tuple<string, string, List<string>>>();

            //n^2, construct lookup for list entities
            foreach (var item in listEntities)
            {
                string listEntityName = item.name;
                foreach (var innerItem in item.subLists)
                {
                    string normalizedValue = innerItem.canonicalForm;
                    List<string> synonymValues = innerItem.list;

                    ListEntityLookup.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string, List<string>>(listEntityName, normalizedValue, synonymValues));
                }
            }

            List<JObject> parsedEntities = new List<JObject>();

            //n^3, populate the parsed payload with start and end indices
            foreach (var item in allUtterances)
            {
                foreach (var ll in ListEntityLookup)
                {
                    foreach (var cf in ll.Item3)
                    {
                        int start = 0, end = 0;
                        if (item.Contains(cf))
                        {
                            start = item.IndexOf(cf);
                            end = start + cf.Length;




                            parsedEntities.Add(new JObject
                            {
                                new JProperty("Start", start),
                                new JProperty("End", end),
                                new JProperty("Query", item),
                                new JProperty("CanonicalForm", ll.Item2),
                                new JProperty("ListEntity", ll.Item1)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Group by query
            var groupedParsedEntities = parsedEntities.GroupBy(x => x["Query"]).ToList();



        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I have tried to re-write the for-each loop, but this resulted, in more nesting.

```
            foreach (var item in allUtterances)
            {
                foreach (var listEntity in listEntities)
                {
                    foreach (var canonicalForm in listEntity.subLists)
                    {
                        foreach(var synonym in canonicalForm.list)
                        {
                            int start = item.IndexOf(synonym);
                            if(start != -1)
                            {
                                parsedEntities.Add(new JObject
                                {
                                    new JProperty("Start", start),
                                    new JProperty("End", start + synonym.Length),
                                    new JProperty("Query", item),
                                    new JProperty("CanonicalForm", canonicalForm.canonicalForm),
                                    new JProperty("ListEntity", listEntity.name)
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

But this approach seems to slow for large number of utterances and does not scale very well. As the main loop runs n^3 times. Our server will have to do too many computations per second.

I am stuck thinking whether or not, should I use Regex if it would offer me some performance benefits or not.

Please help me with optimizing this algorithm.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This might also be a good question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Definitely do not use regex.  String methods are much more efficient than regex.

Comment: @jdweng My main concern is the loop that runs n^3 times, it will be heavy load, and I doubt `.IndexOf()` will be robust/fool-proof or not?

Comment: the regex will be 10x worse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a Linq query, instead of looping?

This does not produce exactly what you need, but I believe that it does extract the relevant data:

```
  allUtterances
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(utterance => listEntities.SelectMany(l => l.subLists
                                .Where(sl => sl.list.Any(sle => utterance.Contains(sle)))
                                .SelectMany(sl => sl.list
                                                    .Where(sle => utterance.Contains(sle))
                                                            .Select(sle => new {
                                                                            canonicalForm = sl.canonicalForm,
                                                                            matchedValue = sle, 
                                                                            startindex = utterance.IndexOf(sle),
                                                                            endindex = utterance.IndexOf(sle) + sle.Length - 1
                                                                        })
                                )
                                .Select(o => new {
                                    // not sure if 'entity' and 'resolutionValue' are swopped around
                                        utterance = utterance,
                                        entity = o.matchedValue,
                                        type = l.name,
                                        startIndex = o.startindex,
                                        endIndex = o.endindex,
                                        resolutionValue = o.canonicalForm,
                                    }
                                )
                            /*
                            or change the Select above to create the JObjects:
                            .Select(jo => new JObject { 
                                new JProperty("Start", jo.startIndex),
                                new JProperty("End", jo.endIndex),
                                new JProperty("Query", jo.utterance),
                                new JProperty("CanonicalForm", jo.resolutionValue),
                                new JProperty("ListEntity", jo.entity)
                            })
                            */
                )).ToList();
```

Or, you could try to parallelize your loops:

```
allUtterances.AsParallel().ForAll(ut => {  .... });
```